# How to build a Dialogflow chatbot for website?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I want to run my first, simple chatbot on my website. So I chose that stack:

- [Dialogflow](https://dialogflow.com) (ML, AI etc.)
- [Dialogflow Messeger](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/integrations/dialogflow-messenger) (frontend communicator app)
- [Firebase Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) with [Dialogflow Fulfillment Library](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs) (backend)

I noticed that Dialogflow Fulfillment Library is no longer maintained. And for example quick replies (rich message) works on [Dialogflow Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJPnh.png), but doesn’t work on [Dialogflow Messenger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RaO2.png).

My code (fulfillment webhook):

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const { WebhookClient } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const { Suggestion } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('richmessage', richMessageButtonHandler);

  function richMessageButtonHandler(agent) {
    agent.add('Select one');
    agent.add(new Suggestion('Quick Reply'));
    agent.add(new Suggestion('Suggestion'));
  }
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Question: I need simple chatbot for website with quick replies (suggestions). Can I achieve that with these technologies (without Facebook Messenger or other external service)? Is any successor? Some alternatives?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

DialogFlow is a good platform (free, NL capabilities, multi-channels) but it is not ideal for web sites, or at least it does not have a specific browser widget.

The DialogFlow web demo is meant for development/testing and cannot be easily customised. There are some options out there (Kommunicate, BotCopy) to add a webchat plugin for a web site or alternatively using the SDK you can build the web chat frontend you want (similar as dialogflow-web-v2 on GitHub)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your BOT part of an Omnichannel platform you can go with Kommunicate. That is the one I'm using it at the moment. BotCopy just integrate your chat into a web page but without the omnichannel capability or, the hardcore one, develop your own with node.js or angular.js etc.  You can try also Twilio Flex but it requires other intermidiate components.

Answer (score -1):

Try Rasa also  (https://rasa.com/)

**positives**

- free
- opensourse
- privacy

**negative**

- need a system resource to run and train bot